# My URL is converted from HTTPS to HTTP using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordovawebview

In cordova, I have a link which opens a HTTPS url.

```
<a href="https://example.com/">Click Here</a>
```

From the Network tab in Chrome developer tools I can see two records:

- My https request - Cancled
- Same url in HTTP without 's' - Blocked.

Why Cordova or WebView converted my URL from HTTPS to HTTP?

URL tested with Chrome desktop without any errors.

Comment: @ malhobayyeb may be your config.xml settings is blocking it. Could you post your config.xml?

Comment: @Gandhi No, my config.xml is allowing everything "*"

Comment: what version of cordova it is? is it possible to the load the code in git and share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your project has the whitelist plugin

```
cordova plugin ls
```

if the list does not show the whitelist plugin then install the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova prepare
```

if it is already install then add this line to the config.xml to allow access to the all request.

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

to give access to only http and https.

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

if the issues persist please post your config.xml

Hope this helps.